# How to fix a "Unexpected state while attempting to read the mapping end" error in Azure DevOps YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to set up a YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps with multiple steps, but I keep encountering a "Unexpected state while attempting to read the mapping end" error. The error message suggests that there is a problem with the formatting of my YAML file, specifically in the `steps` section. I've checked the syntax and formatting rules, but I can't seem to figure out what's causing the error.

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Infrastructure
    type: git
    name: Infrastructure

trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - source/project.test/**
    - source/project.test2/**

steps:
- ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
    - template: Build/build-templateone.yml@Infrastructure
      parameters:
        appName: 'example'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')  

- ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
    - template: Build/build-templatetwo.yml@Infrastructure
      parameters:
        appName: 'example'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')
```

Error:

> Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML: /azure-pipelines.yml
> (Line: 16, Col: 3): Expected at least one key-value pair in the
> mapping /azure-pipelines.yml: Unexpected state while attempting to
> read the mapping end. State:
>
> MappingState:   IsStart: True   Index: 0   IsKey: False   IsEnd: False
>
> SequenceState:   IsStart: False   Index: 1   IsEnd: False
>
> MappingState:   IsStart: False   Index: 3   IsKey: False

IsEnd: False

Answer (score 0):

You were right, it is an indentation problem. The problem is the identation of the template, it's too far out, as well as the condition. The below yaml should validate fine:

```yaml
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Infrastructure
    type: git
    name: Infrastructure

trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - source/project.test/**
    - source/project.test2/**

steps:
- ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
  - template: Build/build-templateone.yml@Infrastructure
    parameters:
      appName: 'example'
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')  

- ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
  - template: Build/build-templatetwo.yml@Infrastructure
    parameters:
      appName: 'example'
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')
```

However, I've never seen the combination of conditions and template expressions and I'm not sure if that would work. Personally I always combine multiple statements in the template expression in this case:

```yaml
- ${{ if and(contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')) }}:
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the doc [Templates - Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-templatecontext-to-pass-properties-to-templates), I tested and confirm you can call a template from a pipeline YAML depending on multiple conditions, just like below.

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Infrastructure
    type: git
    name: Infrastructure

trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - source/project.test/**
    - source/project.test2/**

steps:
- ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI') }}: 
    - template: Build/build-templateone.yml@Infrastructure
      parameters:
        appName: 'example'

- ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI') }}: 
    - template: Build/build-templatetwo.yml@Infrastructure
      parameters:
        appName: 'example'
```

Hope that would be helpful.